# How to connect coax modem/router to a home patch panel?

Tags: coaxial-cable, routers, internet

Please excuse my lack of knowledge here.

I recently moved to a new house and realized the coax cable is in a closet with two ethernet sockets. With some research on the internet I guess this is called a patch panel (not really sure)

So the modem connected via coax cable works fine. The WiFi is working and I connected my laptop directly to the router and the ethernet connection works. So I connected the same ethernet cable to "wohnen" which is the living room and then connected my desktop to the wall socket in the living room via an ethernet cable. Not working unfortunately. I tried connecting to both rooms or to either and still not working.

The LED lights above the LAN connection on the back of the router should be lighting in case it's connected but it's not lighting up.

Could someone point out what am I doing wrong here?

[image: patch panel configuration]

[image: connection to router]

Comment: Always possible the cables are mislabeled. Or miswired. Or cut somewhere.

Comment: You may need a tester like [this Klein, name brand, fairly rugged](https://amzn.to/44edEVn) or [this cheap basic no-name one](https://amzn.to/44edEVn). How much to spend depends on how often you think you'll use it.

Comment: It's possible the wires to the rooms are for telephones and not ethernet.    Can you see on the back of the jacks (or by opening the wall jacks in the rooms) if they appear to be wired correctly for ethernet?  There would be eight wires within each green cable connected to eight pins on the jack.  For phones there would be two or four wires.  The correct number of wires doesn't guarantee it will work but it's a start.   It looks like you might have pullable conduit to the rooms so this might be easy to fix.

Comment: You say, "The LED lights above the LAN connection on the back of the router should be lighting in case it's connected but it's not lighting up." and that's very true. However, those are _link_ lights. They should only light up when equipment is attached at both ends. The router light won't light up just because it's connected to the patch panel. Just making sure we're on the same page...

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're testing everything properly and eliminating the easy failure scenarios.

If you're using that same yellow cable and it works when directly connected to your laptop computer (and the cable you used to connect from your wohnen to your laptop works fine when used to connect directly from your modem to your laptop), then there's a problem with the wiring between the two jacks.  Do you know if this has ever worked?  If you take off the jack cover in your wohnen, are there wires connected to the back of the jack (and same question behind your patch panel - are wires connected)?  Pictures of behind the patch panel (and your wall jack) would be helpful to troubleshoot as well.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I tried also the other cable (was connected to the wall socket) to connect the laptop to the modem and it works. I'm not sure if it worked before because it's a newly built apartment. I will try to look behind the wall socket, otherwise it looks like a problem with wiring and might have to contact the building owners.

Answer (score 0):

Cable goes to modem and then the ethernet ports on the modem get connected to the patch panel (thing with the location labels)

If wired and labelled correctly you should be able to keep the yellow ethernet cable where it is in your photos, and use another ethernet cable to hook up your laptop to the remote port labeled "wohnen"

Answer (score -1):

Based on your descriptions, the problem is not in you cables.

I believe you said the laptop works with any cable and any socket even in the living room. The desktop in living room does not work

The problem is you desktop computer.

Follow this instructions to enable the network card.

https://www.windowscentral.com/how-enable-or-disable-wi-fi-and-ethernet-network-adapters-windows-10

Depending what OS you have find the system controls and the network/internet.

In there find the network card and make sure it is on.

Best test would be if you move your desktop and connect it directly to the modem. Sometimes it is enough if you just restart the computer.

Comment: IDK about all that.  If the "wohnen" port in the panel is really connected to the "wohnen" port in the living room, it should behave exactly as if the computer was connected directly to the router—which the OP said worked fine.

Comment: Having spent an entire career in IT, it's pretty rare for the Ethernet port to be completely disabled out of the box. Granted, everyone seems to like wireless these days, but that doesn't mean wired is _disabled_.

Comment: @FreeMan and yet, there is a software key to disable it

Comment: Sure, you _can_ disable the Ethernet port, but it's _very rare_ that it would be that way out of the box. Also, note that the OP plugged his laptop into the router without the patch panel and it worked just fine, so unless he disabled the port while he plugged in the patch panel, that's not the problem.

Comment: @FreeMan I believe the OP said the laptop works in living room outlet but the desktop does not. Your IT experience means nothing here, people do all kind of wired stuff. Nobody said (`It is out of the box`) where did you get that from ?